# Name for module that's a product of all nontrivial prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I was trying to find module with no maximal proper submodules (such a module can't be finitely generated). **No spoilers please.** So far I have failed, but in the course of looking for one I stumbled across an interesting module, formed by combining all the nontrivial prime elements together and considering the elements with finite support. This gives us something that [reminds me of the product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

**I'm curious what this module is called so I can read more about it.**

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the prime numbers.

The notation $\prod a : A \mathop. B(a)$ is called a dependent type. It is a generalization of a function $A \to B$ except that the codomain is allowed to depend on the domain, so we get something like $A \to B(a)$, except that the association between $a$ and $A$ is explicit.

$R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and $M$ is the subset of $\left(\prod p : \mathbb{P} \mathop. \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \right)$ consisting of functions where only finitely many domain elements are zero, i.e. functions with finite support.

This module has an interesting property; namely that we can use [the Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to isolate parts of the support of each element.

Let $f$ be an element of $\left(\prod p : \mathbb{P} \mathop. \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \right)$ whose support is $\Delta$. For each $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ in $\Delta$ there exists a non-negative integer $k$ such that $kf$ is $1$ mod $p$ and $0$ mod every other prime in $\Delta$.

Thus, the maximal proper submodules of $M$ are precisely the submodules that are constantly zero when we restrict attention to a single prime number $p$ and consider $m_{\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}}$ for each element $m$ of $M$.

Comment: It's called the direct sum of the $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, usually written $\bigoplus_{p\in \mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. You can read more about direct sums in, I would say, any book that covers modules, so any book about commutative algebra, basically.